# When inputting 1 name with no spaces it says 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++, string

I am supposed to enter a name. If this name has no spaces I want to print the name till it has two space and if it has 1 space I want to print the last name one more time.

For example, if I enter `Sara`, I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>     what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this-">size() (which is 4)

```
int SpaceCounter=0;
for(int i=0;i<=name.length();i++)
{
  if(name[i] == ' ')
  {
    SpaceCounter++;
  }
}
if(SpaceCounter>=2)
{
cout<< name;
}
else if(SpaceCounter=1)
{

    size_t pos = name.find(" ");
    string str3 = name.substr (pos);  
    cout <<name<<str3;
    //break;

}
else if(SpaceCounter=0)
{
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    cout <<name<<" ";
  }
}
```

Comment: `else if(SpaceCounter=1)` => `else if(SpaceCounter==1)`

Comment: You do remember that array and string indexes start from zero. But you forget that because of that the top index is `length - 1`.

Comment: You may want to get rid of the `for` loop for printing `name` twice.  Maybe more efficient to do: `cout << name << " " << name << " ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it in wrong way. You can remove additional spaces when you find them. You should also beware of single `=` in conditions.  Here's an some kind of a better version: (not tested)

```
void f(const std::string& name) {
    unsigned spaces = 0;
    std::string out;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
        if(name[i] == ' ') {
            if(spaces == 0)
                // allow one space
                out += name[i];
            spaces++;
        } else 
            out += name[i];
    }
    if(spaces == 0)
        // no spaces found, print 2 times
        std::cout << out << ' ' << out << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for(int i=0;i<=name.length();i++)
```

Change `<=` to `<`. As written it runs off the end of the string, which is what the exception is telling you.